# resize the uploaded picture with php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a plattform where users upload a image on my site. The image is first resized before being moved to a specific folder on the server. The thing is that everything is working except one thing. When the resize procedure is done it cuts out a portion of the image, not actually resizing the image. I am trying to find out what the problem is but I'm only a novice on php. Do you guys have any suggestions to what the problem might be?

```
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $file = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];   

function resize_image($file, $width, $height) {
    list($w, $h) = getimagesize($file);
    /* calculate new image size with ratio */
    $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
    $h = ceil($height / $ratio);
    $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
    $w = ceil($width / $ratio);
    /* read binary data from image file */
    $imgString = file_get_contents($file);
    /* create image from string */
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,
    0, 0,
    $x, 0,
    $width, $height,
    $w, $h);
    imagejpeg($tmp, $file, 100);
    return $file;
    /* cleanup memory */
    imagedestroy($image);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
}

$check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);      
    if($check == false) {
    echo "Filen &auml;r ingen bild!&nbsp;<a href=addPost>Tillbaka</a>";
    exit;
    }
    if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Din bild &auml;r f&ouml;r stor!&nbsp;<a href=addPost>Tillbaka</a>";
    exit;
    }
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Endast jpg, png, jpeg samt gif bilder &auml;r till&aring;tna!&nbsp;<a href=addPost>Tillbaka</a>";
    exit;
    }
    else {
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
    move_uploaded_file(resize_image($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], 200, 200), "uploads/" . $newfilename);
    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $newfilename, 0644);
    }
```